# Unable to find a valid OpenGL 3.2 or later implementation

Tags: python, opengl, x11, remote-access

**Scenario**: I ssh into a remote server with X11forwarding enabled, trying to display image window directly on my client machine. When I run the folloing basic [vedo](https://github.com/marcomusy/vedo/blob/master/examples/notebooks/sphere.ipynb) code:

```
from vedo import *

s = Sphere().cutWithPlane(normal=(1,1,1))
scals = s.points()[:,2] # use z-coords to color vertices

# NB, actions can be concatenated into a pipeline:
# add point scalars with a choice of color map, use flat shading, print infos and then show
s.cmap('Set3', scals).addScalarBar()
plt = s.show(axes=1, viewup='z', backend='ipyvtk')
plt
```

However, it gives me:

```
[        9DD08740]vtkOpenGLRenderWindow.c:499    ERR| vtkXOpenGLRenderWindow (0x5629445fbed0): Unable to find a valid OpenGL 3.2 or later implementation. Please update your video card driver to the latest version. If you are using Mesa please make sure you have version 11.2 or later and make sure your driver in Mesa supports OpenGL 3.2 such as llvmpipe or openswr. If you are on windows and using Microsoft remote desktop note that it only supports OpenGL 3.2 with nvidia quadro cards. You can use other remoting software such as nomachine to avoid this issue.
Segmentation fault
```

**Remote server**: ubuntu 20.04 with 5 Geforce 3090 GPUs.

**Client**: Big Sur 11.6 with AMD 5500M and XQuartz 2.8.2 with `iglx` enabled.

Official documents tell me that 3090 support OpenGL up to 4.6. However, when I type `glxinfo | grep OpenGL` on **server machine**, it gives me:

```
OpenGL vendor string: ATI Technologies Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon Pro 5500M OpenGL Engine
OpenGL version string: 1.4 (2.1 ATI-4.5.14)
OpenGL extensions:
```

where `2.1 ATI-4.5.14` is the OpenGL version on client machine, and `1.4` is the OpenGL version on the remote server.

**My analysis**
It seems like this plot needs OpenGL >= 3.2. Some of the answers asks me to install newest nvidia driver.

But when I run `ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`, another error occurs:

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-7DzKEt/135-nvidia-compute-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
 /tmp/apt-dpkg-install-7DzKEt/140-nvidia-utils-450_450.36.06-0ubuntu1_amd64.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

and neither `apt --fix-broken install` nor `dpkg -i --force-overwrite` fix the issue.

Here's the full story of my problem. I don't know what caused this reason. It might not be the nvidia driver issue because everything works fine when I run pytorch on GPU.

Comment: Indirect rendering (and that's what X11 forwarding is) will only work for GL <= 2.x. The glX network protocol for functions beyond that _does not even exist_. You cannot run modern GL that way.

Comment: @derhass How should I make it run from an remote server in a headless mode?

Comment: You might be able to use some other remote access method, but for true headless operation, there needs to be support for it in the application itself. For example, [nvidia supports headless GL via EGL](https://developer.nvidia.com/blog/egl-eye-opengl-visualization-without-x-server/).